# IIS Reverse Proxy to ASP.NET Core

Tags: iis, asp.net-core, reverse-proxy

I have a local ASP.NET Core site running at `https://localhost:44359` (in IIS Express). For local testing I need this to answer to some domains, so I tried setting up a Reverse Proxy in IIS for this and installed "Application Request Routing" and "Reverse Proxy" (I tried setting up IIS hosting, which causes a whole load of other problems, so lets stick to reverse proxy for now).

First I created a new Website in IIS, pointed it to some folder on my harddrive and added the domain name bindings (and use a wildcard certificate for the domain), finally adding `127.0.0.1 example.com` to my `hosts` file. This works just fine and I can access the IIS site on `https://example.com` or `https://example.net`.

Now I try to add reverse proxy to the site using the following rule in the "URL Rewrite" module:

[image: IIS Reverse Proxy settings]

When I try to access `https://example.com` I get a `HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway` with the message `The connection with the server was terminated abnormally`. If I try without using SSL Offloading I get another simpler error page with the message `Bad Request - Invalid Hostname`.

So how can I set up a reverse proxy in IIS to forward request to my ASP.NET Core site?

**UPDATE:**

I managed to take a Failed Request Tracing Log, which can be found here:

- https://pastebin.com/UZFNzKRr (Without SSL Offloading)
- https://pastebin.com/XCAX2Ngr (With SSL Offloading)

**UPATE 2:**

I had a hunch this might be because of the ASP.NET Core app using a localhost certificate, and the reverse proxy site using a certificate for the domain, so I tried turning off SSL redirects in the ASP.NET Core app to make it respond to regular HTTP requests, but I'm unfortunately getting the same errors. (I'm still not 100% convinced it has something to do with certificates, though)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: @LexLi Any tips on what to look for?

Comment: FRT must also be enabled at site level, not merely create rules. If you find it too hard to troubleshoot, open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com

Comment: @DavidAnderson Unfortunately not. I'm now running Apache frontend with an Apache reverse proxy to IIS (and other services) instead.